Off-topic speculation that requires moderator intervention
This answer to the question "Why did Nicaragua file a case against only Germany at the ICJ?" goes off on a tangent in attempting to explain why the case will not succeed. Not only is this not relevant to the question, it is also pure speculation and therefore needs to be removed for two reasons.
I have already removed it once, and so to avoid starting an edit war, I am bringing it up here.
Please note, that in the past we have far more on topic content deleted. See Italian Philosophers 4 Monica's (now deleted) answer here for an example.


This site is not for promoting opinions, and your views on why you think the case is going to fail is purely your opinion. You have not even attempted to back it up with any source. But even if you had, the most that you would achieve would be to promote someone else's opinion. Until the case is decided, any speculation on its possible outcome will be precisely that, speculation.

If you look at other answers to that question, they aren't great either. Many of them are simply speculating. Maybe the true answer to that question is that we simply don't know. While I'm not happy with that amount of speculation, I also think that deletion is not an answer either. People should simply downvote and move on. This is the best possible behavior in 90% of all cases.

Top answer starts with "Unclear why the US was left out" Maybe it should have stopped there. Later it goes on with "I suspect..." which is also just speculation.

The entire on-topic part of of the answer is

They probably chose Germany because its symbolic since they
committed the holocaust.

There is a flag that reads "Very low quality" which I think applies here (sorry Calle). Politics.SE should answers should be more than guesses. The question itself kind of invites guesses, but the other answers at least cites some evidence in support of their guesswork. The highest voted answer cites the US reservation and German arms exports to Israel. Another answer cites German oppression of pro-Palestinian speech. A third Germany's left-wing government which the answerer thinks is more susceptible to court proceedings.


Not only is this not relevant to the question...

It kind of is (or rather would be under different circumstances). The prospect of winning a case surely is part of the motivation to file it. Then when you file a case and are asked why you do that, you might want to say that you are convinced that you are going to win it.
In this case however, Nicaragua doesn't seem to have said so and the author would have a hard time using his/her opinion about the low success rate as a motivation. If anything it would be the opposite, a reason not to file.
On the political stage, actors might even be motivated to file cases if they do not expect them to win, just for the publicity. Might even be the case here. Maybe that is what the author meant. In that case, a statement about the low success probability would be helpful, but without inside information rather speculative.
It's a tangent that is vaguely related but in no way backed up (by similar cases, by what Nicaragua said itself, ...). So rather not useful. Edits against the will of the original author are a bit problematic too, so rather just downvote and move on. The "Very low quality" flag is a bazooka and can be misused. I wouldn't use it here, but your mileage may vary.

Answer has been deleted now but this seems to me over the top. Voted to undelete. Come on. Other answers are also just speculation ("I am guessing...") or go off about Germans presumably not allowed to discuss Palestinian matters. Do you want to delete them all?
